# skip duplicate entry in foreach mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, duplicate-data, skip

hi friends i need to **skip** a **duplicate** entries in **foreach** and than **continue** on remaining ones please tell me how can i do this

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$arr1)
{
    echo "<pre>";

$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO auth_user(id,username,first_name,last_name,email,password,is_active,date_joined) VALUES('".$key."','".$arr1['username']."','".$arr1['firstname']."','".$arr1['lastname']."','".$arr1['email']."','NULL','".$arr1['is_active']."','".$arr1['date_joined']."')",$conn1);

echo $insert .'<br/>';
if($insert)
    {
        echo "DATA MIGRATE FOR USER ".$key;
        $insert1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO stylequiz_score(user_id,style_quiz_score,style_quiz_answer) VALUES('".$key."','".$arr1['style_quiz_score']."','".$arr1['style_quiz_answer']."')",$conn1);
    }
    else
    {
       echo  ("Error In MIGRATION FOR USER ".$key . mysql_error());

    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know if it's duplicate?

Comment: Suggest to use `unique`, `primary key` and/or similar database technique to prevent duplication.

Comment: acctauly there are thousands of entries i need to import and i dont want to break the script in between due to some reason , i want if due to some reason the script breaks in between , next time when i start again run script it should not throw any error , right now it is not inserting anything after it breaks occurs and try to import next time

Comment: So you don't mean duplicates in the array, you mean entries that duplicate something already in the table? Does `INSERT IGNORE` do what you want?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want , i want to skip the entries which already exists  , how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the IGNORE modifier of the INSERT statement:

```
$insert1=mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO stylequiz_score(user_id,style_quiz_score,style_quiz_answer) VALUES('".$key."','".$arr1['style_quiz_score']."','".$arr1['style_quiz_answer']."')",$conn1);
```

If the row being inserted would get a duplicate key error, this modifier causes the insert to be skipped with no error.

Comment: Hi Barmar i think i can learn a lot from you , can you give me your id where i can talk with you if possible thanks

Comment: No, sorry, I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

array_unique will remove all the duplicate values in the array. In your case, try like this.

```
$arr = array_unique($arr);
```

You don't need to do any extra functions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have duplicate values in `$arr`

use `array_unique`

```
$res_array = array_unique($arr);
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

To check duplicate in databse, put your insert query in if condition

```
$sql   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE email = '".$arr1['email']."'");
if(mysql_numrows($sql) == 0){
   $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO auth_user(id,username,first_name,last_name,email,password,is_active,date_joined) VALUES('".$key."','".$arr1['username']."','".$arr1['firstname']."','".$arr1['lastname']."','".$arr1['email']."','NULL','".$arr1['is_active']."','".$arr1['date_joined']."')",$conn1);
}
else{
   $insert = false;
}
```

Comment: actually what i want is if due to some reason script breaks in between , the next time when i start again script it should not throw any error and skip the entries which already exists and continue after that